# Detect touches on a UIView inside UIScrollView preferably with Interaction disabled

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with some `UIViews` in it.
What I am trying to do, is catch the touches events when the UIViews are touched/untouched.

The problem I am having, is the `UIScrollView` seems to swallow all the touch events, especially if you hold for too long on a `UIView`.

I preferably want the `UIScrollView` to have userInteraction disabled as it scrolls automatically.

Is this possible?

I have tried subclassing the `UIViews` but the touches events are never called in it.

Answer (score 4):

You can attach a `tapGesture` to your `scrollview` with something along those lines:

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureUpdated:)];
   tapGesture.delegate = self;
   tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
   [self addGestureRecognizer:_tapGesture];
```

then in your `- (void)tapGestureUpdated:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture` method this is your responsability to determine the location of the touch and find out if there was a picking on one of your subviews. You could call then a method on a delegate that notify that a specific view has been touched.

Comment: Would this method only be called once? I want the length if time touch is on the UIView, so need the touchStart and touchEnd events.

Comment: the tapGesture argument has a state such as UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan or UIGestureRecognizerStateEnd i would use this to detect the two touch events you are interested

Comment: make sure u read the official doc on the tapgesture though: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this method in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps reordering your views so that a view that has a touch recognizer object associated with  it is what the app recognizes. Move it in the document outline to the top (scroll view)

Comment: I did think of this, but I think it will be very hard to move the UIView the same speed as the scroll view

Comment: @Darren Hmmm. What about a UIButton set to custom and with an alpha bg set to 0.0? Also, if you add a UIView, it doesn't necessarily have to move with the UIScrollView...